# How can I add already calculated standard error values to each bar in a bar plot (ggplot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 6 genes which I want to compare the effect size ( following linear mixed models) between two groups ( control-crohns and control-ulcerative colitis). My bars will be both positive and negative and there are 6 genes altogether.

Here is my data:

```
structure(list(Gene1 = c(-0.017207751, 
-0.00939068, 0.007440363, 0.004574254), Gene2 = c(0.025987401, 
 0.025625772, 0.010239336, 0.00695056), Gene3 = c(0.018122943, 0.012997113, 
 0.008892864, 0.006541982), Gene4 = c(-0.022694115, 
-0.009823328, 0.007286011, 0.004776522), Gene5 = c(0.031315514, 
 0.013967722, 0.008674407, 0.00674662), Gene6 = c(-0.016374358, 
-0.009660298, 0.007140279, 0.004536602)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Control_Crohns", 
 "Control_UC", "Std.error_controlcrohns", "Std.errorr_controluc"
))
```

I have just extracted this data from a bigger set ( and therefore would like to keep the standard errors from the larger data set). I can plot the graph with just the bars for each of the genes using the following ( I removed the last two rows of the above with the std.error for each group to do this).

```
  datframe2=data.frame(Group=rownames(data), data)


  datframe.m <- melt(datframe2, id.vars = "Group")  


graph <- ggplot(datframe.m, aes(x = variable, y= value, fill=Group)) +geom_bar(aes(variable, value), 
 stat= "identity", width=0.8, position="dodge")

graph + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) + xlab("Gene") + 
ylab("Estimate")
```

However, I do not know how to add the calculated std.error values to each bar using geom_errorbar using the original data above. Please could somebody direct me to an example ( as I haven't been able to find one where they add already pre-existing values, and a similar question on here did not help). Thank-you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to reshape your dataframe in order to make your data simpler to use in `gglot2`.

When it is about to reshape data into a longer format with multiples columns names as output, I prefered to use `melt` function from `data.table` package. But you can get a similar result with `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr`.

At the end, your dataset should look like this:

```r
library(data.table)
DF <- as.data.frame(t(DF))
DF$Gene <- rownames(DF)

DF.m <- melt(setDT(DF), measure = list(grep("Control_",colnames(DF)),grep("Std.error",colnames(DF))),
     value.name = c("Control","SD"))

     Gene variable      Control          SD
 1: Gene1        1 -0.017207751 0.007440363
 2: Gene2        1  0.025987401 0.010239336
 3: Gene3        1  0.018122943 0.008892864
 4: Gene4        1 -0.022694115 0.007286011
 5: Gene5        1  0.031315514 0.008674407
 6: Gene6        1 -0.016374358 0.007140279
 7: Gene1        2 -0.009390680 0.004574254
 8: Gene2        2  0.025625772 0.006950560
 9: Gene3        2  0.012997113 0.006541982
10: Gene4        2 -0.009823328 0.004776522
11: Gene5        2  0.013967722 0.006746620
12: Gene6        2 -0.009660298 0.004536602
```

Then, you can easily plot with `ggplot2` by using `geom_errorbar` for standard deviation of each genes.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(DF.m, aes(x = Gene, y= Control, fill = as.factor(variable)))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Control-SD,ymax = Control+SD), position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.2)+
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Disease", labels = c("Crohns", "UC"))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: @dc37 Thank-you very much for this. My data set contains 8 genes altogether, when I run the above it seems to group those genes where the value is negative together and then the positive ones are also together. Please could you tell me is there anything I can add to the code to keep the genes in the same order?

Comment: Are they display according alphabetical order ?

Comment: You can specify the order by passing this command before `ggplot`: `DF.m$Gene <- factor(DF.m$Gene, levels = c("Gene1","Gene2", ...)`. Let me know if it is working

Comment: @dc37 Thanks for your reply. Yes, they are ( named them Gene 1-6 here) but the real names have been arranged alphabetically. Is there any way to prevent this at all?

Comment: See my answer below, in `levels` pass the order you would like to be displayed and it should work

Comment: @dc37 Thank-you, it works! I notice from your profile that you are self-educated in R. If there are any resources in particular that you recommend to increase proficiency, please could you post them somewhere if possible? I'll keep practising anyway.

Comment: You're welcome ;). i think you can find good resources on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. I recently start the R for Data Science book. It's rally interesting but maybe a little too much advanced. However, I personaly start by reading R for dummies and looking on R blogger posts trying to reproduce their example. A good way to learn is to try to reproduce what people are posting by deconstructin the code step by step to understand the logic behind. But it takes times ;). Good luck anyway !! ;D

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your `datframe2` and `datframe.m` code, but I would highly recommend transforming your data into "long", instead of the matrix-like format it is currently in.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Gene1 = c(-0.017207751, -0.00939068, 0.007440363, 0.004574254), 
                     Gene2 = c(0.025987401, 0.025625772, 0.010239336, 0.00695056), 
                     Gene3 = c(0.018122943, 0.012997113, 0.008892864, 0.006541982), 
                     Gene4 = c(-0.022694115, -0.009823328, 0.007286011, 0.004776522), 
                     Gene5 = c(0.031315514, 0.013967722, 0.008674407, 0.00674662), 
                     Gene6 = c(-0.016374358, -0.009660298, 0.007140279, 0.004536602)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Control_Crohns", "Control_UC", "Std.error_controlcrohns", "Std.errorr_controluc"))

df %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "variable") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-variable, names_to = "gene", values_to = "value") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  gene  Control_Crohns Control_UC Std.error_controlcrohns Std.errorr_controluc
  <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>                   <dbl>                <dbl>
1 Gene1        -0.0172   -0.00939                 0.00744              0.00457
2 Gene2         0.0260    0.0256                  0.0102               0.00695
3 Gene3         0.0181    0.0130                  0.00889              0.00654
4 Gene4        -0.0227   -0.00982                 0.00729              0.00478
5 Gene5         0.0313    0.0140                  0.00867              0.00675
6 Gene6        -0.0164   -0.00966                 0.00714              0.00454
```

It will be much easier to use `ggplot2` with your data in this format.